# windows 11 "low battery action" is missing "sleep" option

Tags: windows, battery, sleep, power

my laptop able to go to sleep just fine via sleep button, closing the lid, or timer. but the windows "low battery action" is missing "sleep" option.

so it only got this option: do nothing, turn off, hibernate.

in other devices, it also has an option to sleep.

how to add the sleep option? any command and/or registry key edits?

Answer (score 0):

Although *Sleep* was available as on option for *Critical battery action* on Windows 10, it is *not* good practice, and might have been removed in Windows 11, for good reason.

[image: Sleep option]

[*Sleep*, as opposed to *Hibernate*](https://www.howtogeek.com/102897/whats-the-difference-between-sleep-and-hibernate-in-windows/), uses electricity to keep the CPU running in a low-power state. However, "low power" still drains the battery. If the battery is *already* low, putting the laptop to sleep will shut the display, but still uses power, and soon there would not be enough to safely shut down or to *Hibernate* from *Sleep*. The machine state and unsaved data would be lost, and possibly damage could be done to the file system.

This does not stop *you* from manually putting the machine to sleep when the battery is low... and any issue resulting from eventual loss of power would be your responsibility.

Comment: thats why i put the low battery trigger to 10%, and critical to 5% to hibernate. the problem is, the "sleep" option is missing both in critical and low.

Comment: on my other windows 11 device, the sleep option is not missing from both critical and low battery.

Comment: The Sleep option might be missing because of Group Policy setting (fixable) or because some devices do not support it. See https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-10-fix-mising-sleep-option/ for remedies.  BTW, I'd suggest leaving a larger margin for critical shutdown -- battery service life is shortened by deep cycling.